# Jquery CSS show current div on click in another cotainer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html.

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="float:left">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div id='rm-a'>
            <div class="room-canvas">
            <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
            <div class="pimg" style=' background-image:url(<?php echo "http://iaz.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product".$this->getProduct(); ?>);'>rm-1</div>
            </div></div></div>
        
            <div id='rm-b'>
            <div class="room-canvas">
            <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
            <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-b</div>
            </div></div></div>
                                
            <div id='rm-c'>
            <div class="room-canvas">
            <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
            <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-c</div>
            </div></div></div>                            
       
    
         </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"></div>  //container
        </div>
```

What I am looking to achieve is:
div class `rm-a` , `rm-b` and `rm-c` act as a thumbnail anchor to bigger image container.
so when div `rm-a` is clicked,

the same div will be copied in the container
`<div class="col-lg-6"></div>`

when `rm-b` is clicked it will replace the by `rm-b` in the container.

I had a go at it, also found one example at [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp](http://W3school)

but that deals with images and src, whereas in my example it is all divs with background images, somehow not able to adept the same correctly.

my code link at JSfiddle is - https://jsfiddle.net/yoc9qvrb/12/

Comment: You are using bootstrap-3 right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy the content of div and using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) you can update the content in the target div.

```js
$('#rm-a,#rm-b,#rm-c').click(function(){
  var target = $(this).parent().next();
  target.html('');
  var copiedDiv = $(this).clone();
  target.html(copiedDiv);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="float:left">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div id='rm-a'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style=' background-image:url(<?php echo "http://iaz.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product".$this->getProduct(); ?>);'>rm-1</div>
        </div></div></div>

        <div id='rm-b'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.cubereach.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-b</div>
        </div></div></div>

        <div id='rm-c'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.cubereach.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-c</div>
        </div></div></div>                            


     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>  //container
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="float:left">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div id='rm-a'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style=' background-image:url(<?php echo "http://iaz.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product".$this->getProduct(); ?>);'>rm-1</div>
        </div></div></div>

        <div id='rm-b'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.cubereach.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-b</div>
        </div></div></div>

        <div id='rm-c'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.cubereach.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-c</div>
        </div></div></div>                            


     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>  //container
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="float:left">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div id='rm-a'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style=' background-image:url(<?php echo "http://iaz.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product".$this->getProduct(); ?>);'>rm-1</div>
        </div></div></div>

        <div id='rm-b'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.cubereach.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-b</div>
        </div></div></div>

        <div id='rm-c'>
        <div class="room-canvas">
        <div class="tp1-rm-a" style='background-image:url(http://iaz.example.com/Template1.jpg);'>
        <div class="pimg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'http://iaz.cubereach.com/pub/media/catalog/product'.$this->getProduct(); ?>);">rm-c</div>
        </div></div></div>                            


     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>  //container
    </div>
```

Comment: do we need to keep the same code in target container as well? is it not possible to clone the source div, being clicked to target container div.?

Comment: The code is cloning the source div and updating the target div.

Comment: I have created a JSfiddle with your suggested code, but if I change the Css class `.canvas{min-width:300px;}` it works on 2nd and 3rd div, but not on first. if I remove the min-width. on clicking it only shows third div irespective of where I clicked. can you please have a look. link - https://jsfiddle.net/yoc9qvrb/12/

Comment: Your class `.room-canvas::after` is messing with the html, that's why you are not getting the desired result. Remove it and the code will work.

Comment: Thanks. I already identified that. Yes that was causing the issue. I accepted the answer. Thank you once again.